# 401 Unauthorized when getting app list for LG TV Using ConneckSDK

Tags: ios, swift, webos, live-connect-sdk

Using [ConnectSDK](http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/ios/launch-tv-app/). I can successfully connect to a device and running `device.launcher().launchNetflix()` actually launches Netflix. However, most apps are launched using `device.launcher().launchApp(appID: String)`, but no where am I able to find out what the appID is for each app. My initial thought was to use `device.launcher().getAppList()` to get a list of apps and load them into the tableview, but this throws a 401 user not authorized error.

Comment: The part where I'm not authorized to view the apps on my own TV.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an extra pairing step is required for [certain features](http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/SupportedFeatures/) and just connecting is not enough. Instructions on pairing can be found [here](http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/docs/1-5-0/ios/discovery-manager/). Just scroll down to where it says "Pairing Level". Essentially your code should look like this:

```
discoveryManager = DiscoveryManager.shared()
discoveryManager?.pairingLevel = DeviceServicePairingLevelOn
discoveryManager?.startDiscovery()
```

This will require the user to enter a code from their TV into your app. Once they have paired, the 401 errors should go away for most these features.